# Create a vector that points to elements in another in C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, vector

Good afternoon,

I can't seem to be able to make a duplicate std::vector without copying it.
I need to make a vector that points to another std::vector without copying every value

If I write

```
vector_1 = vector_0;
```

In the watch window, `&vector_1` and `&vector_0` have completely different memory addresses

Same with  `&vector_1[0]` and `&vector_0[0]` , so I understand this operation copies the vector.

However, when I try to write `&vector_1[0] = &vector_0[0];` or 
    `&vector_1 = &vector_0;`

I get the error 
`Error  C2106   '=': left operand must be l-value`

I also tried creating a vector this way:

`std::vector<float> vector_1(vector_0[0], vector_0.size());` , but the `&vector_1` and `&vector_0` and `&vector_1[0]` and `&vector_0[0]` show different memory addresses, so it appears to be copying the elements again.

Thanks,

Comment: `std::vector` doesn't support having it's state shared. In fact, no type supports  having it's address assigned to.

Comment: @François Nor does any other class.

Comment: Maybe you want a `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>>`.

Comment: Why do you need this?  Can't you just pass it by/create a reference to the vector?

Comment: I have a sections of code that need to use the same large vector but have to refer to it by different names. Sectioned by #defines, one section actually copies and restructures the vector, another section does not, but later in the code it has to refer to the new vector

Comment: Okay, so pass the vector to each part by reference.

Comment: `auto & vector_1 = vector_0;` should work ?

Comment: This sounds like you need a **reference**. `std::vector<whatever>& vec = vector_0;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need `y` to simply be the same vector as `x`, make it a reference:

```
std::vector<int> x = {1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<int> & y = x;

assert(std::addressof(x) == std::addressof(y));
```

If you need `y` to be reassignable, make it a pointer:

```
std::vector<int> x = {1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<int> * y = &x;

assert(std::addressof(x) == y);
```

If you need `y` to share ownership of `x`, make them both a `std::shared_ptr`:

```
auto x = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>({1,2,3,4,5});
auto y = x;

assert(x.get() == y.get());
```

If you need `y` to be its own vector, but contain references to the objects in `x`, make `y` a `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>>` or `std::vector<int*>`:

```
std::vector<int> x = {1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> y(x.begin(), x.end());

for(size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
    assert(std::addressof(x[i]) == std::addressof(y[i].get()));

//OR save pointers...
std::vector<int*> y;
for(int & i : x)
    y.emplace_back(std::addressof(i));

for(size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
    assert(std::addressof(x[i]) == y[i]);

//OR save iterators...
std::vector<decltype(x.begin())> y;
for(auto it = x.begin(); it != x.end(); it++)
    y.emplace_back(it);

for(size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
    assert(std::addressof(x[i]) == std::addressof(*(y[i])));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a reference to the vector

```
std::vector<T> & vector_1 = vector_0;
```

This way, `vector_1` will be an alias for `vector_0`, having the same address and all elements being the same, no copying taking place.

---

**EDIT**

If you instead want to have `vector_0` and `vector_1` share ownership of the same vector, but be independent objects, use a `shared_ptr` as described in [Xiremas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5241642/xirema) answer.